# Controlling timeout of bulk api ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Recently we faced an issue with Elastic Search, where one of our shard node was down. Now while doing a bulk insert operation that complete request was timeout over http.

To play around this:

1. Is there a way to set timeout for each operation at server side?

What I want to do is: If single request fails in bulk operation, we will move to DLQ, in place of retrying the complete bulk operation.

I can see there is option:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-bulk.html#_optional_arguments_4 
to set Timeout, is that http timeout or timeout for each operation?

I can see this is specified here also:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html

Comment: The timeout indicates how long the bulk operation will wait on a primary shard to become available for up to 1 minute before failing and responding with an error. Increasing this timeout might save you, but I'd say you should first fix the "node down" issue.

Comment: @Val yes we resolved the issue about node down, But we were thinking of adding code where a single node going down, doesn't fail all the writes.